# Javascript alert message contains URL

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript function:

```
<!-- Notifying message at the beginning of openning the website -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Sorry!');
    </script>
    <!--End -->
```

I want to add the URL after "(Sorry!)" in the alert message but I don't know how to append the URL to the message itself inside the javascript.

Comment: Did you mean an URL that the user can click on?

Answer (score 5):

Try -

```
alert('Sorry!'+document.URL);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/Fg3eN/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object to get the current value.

```
 alert('Sorry! ' + window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean URL:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var url = "http://www.google.es/";
    alert('Sorry!' + url);
</script>
```

If you mean a *link*, the answer is that **it is not possible**.

Answer (score 2):

This will put the current URL in the alert box. Note that it will not be a hyperlink that is clickable.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Sorry! ' + window.location.href);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.location.href` or `document.URL`, both will work :)

Answer (score -2):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437